# Standard contact field not visible on user object

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout

[image: Screenshot of user's page layout]I have something to do with the standard contact field on user object but when i go and try to edit the layout it doesnot give me any options for standard field. Altgough i am getting options for salesforce1.

I guess my user profile is configured for mobile.Any alternative way i may be missing to change it back so that i can see all the standard fields

Thanks in Advance Guys!!!

Comment: You should be able to set contact field using "User Profile" Layout section in User's Page Layout.

Comment: Wait. let me put that as answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set contact field using "User Profile" Layout section in User's Page Layout.

[image]

Comment: But i am not able to set "User Profile Page Layouts"as default layout .I am still getting the salesforce1 layout and not able to see contact related list

Comment: @AnkitaSingh PageLayout Assignment on same section would help you to set default layout.

Comment: I have assigned the layout the every profile but there is one more section"User Page Layouts" , in which a different layout is assigned to all profile as this one is acting as default